# sql create string variable with column names

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i'm trying to create a dynamic sql statement either thru sql code or c# code. For example, I'd like to generate a result set based on a string containing a table name. Currently, I am doing this thru c# code.

My current issue is I'd like to generate a search similar to following

```
select * from customers
where ContactName+City like '%Berlin%'
```

so I'm thinking given a table name as a string parameter I need to somehow produce a string variable `'ContactName+City+etc'` to build part of the search

I'm open to any other ideas as well.

```
var sql = string.Format(@"
select * from {0}
where {1} like '%criteria%'"
, variable_table
, "column1+column2+columnX"); //need function here to produce this string based on variable table?
```

**Basically**, how would I create a string that concatenates a variable number of columns together (`'ContactName+City+etc'`) based on a variable_table?

Comment: Do you want to select all the columns in the variable_table or only specific set of columns ?

Comment: I'm thinking all columns because I can create a view if I want to limit the columns, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this purely in SQL as well. But as you have already done this in C# and you need only to get the list of columns based on the table name, try this.

Create a SQL udf as below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION funcReturnAllColumns
(
    @tableName VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
BEGIN

DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @ALLColumns VARCHAR(500)

SET @ALLColumns = ''

SELECT @ID = id
FROM sys.sysobjects
WHERE name = @tableName


SELECT @ALLColumns = @ALLColumns + '+' + name 
FROM sys.syscolumns
WHERE id = @ID

RETURN SUBSTRING(@ALLColumns,2,LEN(@ALLColumns))

END


SELECT dbo.funcReturnAllColumns('table_name')
```

OUTPUT:
Column1 + Column2 + ..... + ColumN

You may have to adjust varchar limits, validations as required.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply this:

```
      select * from variable_table_name
      WHERE column1+column2+columnX like '%criteria%'
```